# Unable to pull openshift release image

Tags: openshift-online-2, openshift-origin, openshift, openshift-4, openshift-online-3

I am installing okd following [this](https://medium.com/swlh/guide-okd-4-5-single-node-cluster-832693cb752b) link. After installing coreos on bootstrap node I am getting error "Unable to pull Openshift release image". How can I fix this problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bootstap node needs to be able to pull from image registry. Check your firewall its blocking access.